# getting exception:org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;

Tags: redis

I am trying to use Redis in spring boot application for the session by adding dependencies like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And the code for Redis is like:

```
package com.dci.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericToStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.web.context.AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dci")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());

        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatted the code

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

JedisConnectionFactory and RedisTemplate beans are not needed with Spring boot, but in your file "Spring Security Config" add:

```
     @Bean
     public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
         return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
     }
```

In the pom add the following dependencies:

```
<! - Spring Session ->
<Dependency>
  <GroupId> org.springframework.session </ groupId>
  <ArtifactId> spring-session </ artifactId>
  <Version> 1.3.5.RELEASE </ version>
</ Dependency>

<! - redis server ->
<Dependency>
  <GroupId> org.springframework.data </ groupId>
  <ArtifactId> spring-data-redis </ artifactId>
  </ Dependency>
<Dependency>
  <GroupId> redis.clients </ groupId>
  <ArtifactId> Jedis </ artifactId>
</ Dependency>
```

In your configuration file (es. application.properties) add:
spring.session.store-type = none

Spring Boot will do everything else.